# How does the submit button on a form work?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple form that collects data and sends it to a PHP script using POST.

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="cost">
    <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The PHP script is,

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "set";
}
```

I want to know what happens when I click on the submit button?

The PHP manual says the following about isset,

> isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

When exactly is the submit button SET? When I echo out echo `$_POST['submit'];` it outputs nothing.

It's only when I use the `value` attribute along with the submit button that I get something on `$_POST['submit'];`. Why should I use the `value` with the submit button? What exactly does it do?

Comment: As you quoted it, the value is empty, an empty string. So the variable is set and is not null. I do not see the problem in there.

Comment: The `<button>` is just another field of your form that gets posted to your submission page. If you set the value it will get that value, if not it is an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know what happens when I click on the submit button?

It submits the form.

> When exactly is the submit button SET?

When the user submit's the form.

> When I echo out echo $_POST['submit']; it outputs nothing.

You didn't specified a value for it, so it returns an empty string (`$_POST['submit'] === ""`)

> Why should I use the value with the submit button? What exactly does it do?

Well on an button the value is not needed, it is enough when it is set, so you can check if the button was submitted and not an other form f.ex.

Comment: Thanks @jmattheis, that helps. One question, what is exactly making something set? Is it like declaring a variable but not assigning it a value?

Comment: @innowqhy well you variable has an value the value is just empty. f.ex like this ``$emptystring = ""``; So ``echo $emptystring`` would produce nothing as the value is empty.

Comment: So a value on a form is only required to make sure a particular button was clicked when we have multiple forms?

Comment: You could give the button on the other form an other name, so you only need to check which button is set like ``if($_POST['login']) { // do login stuff } else if($_POST['register']) { // do register stuff } `` or you specify a value, that would work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="cost" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In php side

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=="Submit"){
    echo "set";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It submits the whole form data into targeted location and the **GET** and **POST** methods are used to send encoded data to the targeted location

- The **GET method** is restricted to send upto 1024 characters only.
- The **POST method** does not have any restriction on data size to be sent.